# Union over fields having different names using peewee

Tags: python, sql, orm, peewee

I'm using [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) as ORM and have two classes like this:

```
class A(Model):
    name = CharField()
    body = TextField()

class B(Model):
    title = CharField()
    body = TextField()
```

I would like to get all entries from `A` and `B` whose `title`/`name` start with some characters like `'abc'`. According to the documentation the `|` operator should help, but I'm not even able to execute the resulting `Expression`. Obviously I would like to have a `UNION` and `AS` expression behind the scenes. How do I get this via peewee?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get the result you want with something like

```
result = (
    A().select(A.name.alias('name_title'), A.body).where(A.name == 'abc') |
    B().select(B.title.alias('name_title'), B.body).where(B.title == 'abc')
).select().execute()
```

or

```
search_text = 'abc'
table_a_results = A().select(
    A.name.alias('name_title'),
    A.body
).where(A.name == search_text)
table_b_results = B().select(
    B.name.alias('name_title'),
    B.body
).where(B.title == search_text)

result = ( table_a_results | table_b_results ).select().execute()
```

The `.alias()` method to gets you the `AS` functionality as per the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=alias#Model.alias)